# Removing the whitespaces from a particular column in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I'd like to remove all the whitespace characters and make it lowercase:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[1,2,3,4], "col2":["A","B ", "Cc","D"]})
```

I tried to do that via `df[["col2"]].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower())` but it raises an error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'", 'occurred at index col2')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two function call from `str`

```
df["col2"].str.strip().str.lower()
```